# Allow a user to have access to all root privileges EXCEPT…

Tags: linux, permissions

I'm starting to learn more about Linux security and I know a little bit about granting partial root privileges, but I need to revoke partial root privileges. Say I have two accounts, `admin` and `user`. `admin` is the master account. `user` is the secondary account. How would I set it such that `user` can use `sudo` to do everything it can normally do except, say, change the immutable flag on particular files or have access to raw IO (where they can directly modify processes and filesystems)? Does the native permission system allow for this kind of granularity?

I know that there is thing called [capabilities](http://linux.die.net/man/7/capabilities) which *looks* like it provide the kind of fine-level control I want, but on closer examination operates on a different set of things. Providing for what a user is allowed to do is much more tedious than specifying what they aren't if your question is "What is X not permitted to do?". The documentation on this is extremely sparse.

Answer (score 0):

In general, this is a hard problem, not just on Linux but on all systems. The reason is, to provide full root or admin access except X, you can't just stop there. You also need to restrict access to "the ability to give access to X", and the ability to restrict the ability to give access to X... and so on. You typically end up having to add a lot more restrictions just to restrict a single thing, and some savvy "almost" root users might figure out a way to circumvent it and gain full root privs anyway unless you get it 100% right. For this reason, working the other way is the norm: explicitly grant access to what you want them to have. You are correct that this can be **extremely** tedious, especially if you truly need "root except X", but from a security standpoint it is much safer. Also, as you start building the explicit permissions, you typically come across other things you don't want them to do too, for example you probably don't want AlmostRoot to be able to reset Root's password.